# I want allow user to execute *only* ping utility using SELinux

Tags: selinux, ping

I did it already with rbash (restricted bash) but now I want to use SELinux.

So I created new user and add him to guest_u:

```
semanage login -a -s guest_u restricteduser
```

also I forbid him to execute anything:

```
setsebool allow_guest_exec_content=0
```

And here I should allow him only ping to execute.

And also I need somehow allow him some network. How can I do this?

Comment: Does your user needs a shell too? And - just wondering - since `ping` is setuid root, does the guest user actually need any network access?

Comment: What do you mean by shell? sh scripts? And yes I want to add some more network utilities for him ex. ssh client, so I need to enable port 22

Answer (score 0):

[`allow_guest_exec_content`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-confining_users-booleans_for_users_executing_applications) boolean controls whether user in `guest_t` can execute files in home or temporary directories. User is otherwise still allowed to run other executables as policy permits.

SELinux reference policy provides interfaces to allow specific access. These interfaces are listed in SELinux policy [documentation](http://oss.tresys.com/docs/refpolicy/api/) (your distribution likely provides them in `selinux-policy-doc` package).

To allow guest user to use ping, you could use [`netutils_exec_ping`](http://oss.tresys.com/docs/refpolicy/api/admin_netutils.html#link_netutils_exec_ping) interface.

Then create a module for your custom policy, for example
*my_guest.te*:

```
policy_module(my_guest, 1.0)

gen_require(`
    type guest_t;
    role guest_r;
')

netutils_run_ping(guest_t, guest_r)
```

and compile it with:

```
make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile my_guest.pp
```

Depending on what kind of network access you want to allow, you can look for suitable interface and use it in same way to extend `my_guest` module.

Comment: If I want to forbid execution any file I must write files_exec_usr_files (guest_t, guest_r) netutils_run_ping(guest_t, guest_r)? What about shell itself?

Comment: SELinux should already allow `guest_t` to execute a file with `bin_t` label (you can verify with `sesearch -A  -s guest_t -t bin_t`), which is applied on many installed executables as default (see `semanage fcontext -l|grep bin_t`). SELinux confines *all* processes in `guest_t` domain. Other applications executed run in the same `guest_t` domain (unless the policy contains a rule allowing transition to another domain).